# Localization in moqui framework

Tags: moqui

In moqui framework, how to implement localization for different labels for differrnt tenants. for eg tenant related xml cong files

Comment: don't give down vote. It is important for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All translations are in the tables for the LocalizedMessage and LocalizedEntityField entities, and those tables are in a separate database for each tenant. To use different translations for different tenants just add and modify records in the database for each tenant as needed. This can be done using the Localization screens in the System app when authenticated in the desired tenant.